# Nesting NumPy arrays and using methods like splitting them

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, split

I am new to NumPy and am trying to use it in my code for some tables.

I have a list of coordinates that looks like this:

```
coordinates = [["2 0"], ["0 1"], ["3 4"]]
```

and want to write it like this:

```
coordinatesNumpy = np.array([[2, 0], [0, 1], [3, 4]])
```

In regular Python that's easy to do but how do you do it with NumPy? Should I just make the table with regular Python functions for lists and then convert the 2d table to `np.array` or does NumPy have methods for splitting and stuff?

I tried some things but they all give me an error. The latest thing I tried:

```
flowers = np.array([np.array([int(coordinate[0]), int(coordinate[2])]) for coordinate in coordinates])
```

How could I do something like this with NumPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## List comprehension with pure Python

This works:

```
>>> flowers = np.array([[int(x)  for x in coordinate[0].split()] 
                        for coordinate in coordinates])
>>> flowers
array([[2, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
```

I am not aware of any NumPy function that would do this in one step.

### Performance

Let's check how fast things are.

For your example data, the pure Python version is the fastest:

```
%timeit np.array([np.fromstring(i, dtype=int, sep=' ') for j in coordinates for i in j])
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.4 µs per loop

%timeit np.array([np.fromstring(item[0], dtype=int, sep=' ').tolist() for item in coordinates])
10000 loops, best of 3: 19 µs per loop

%timeit np.array([[int(x)  for x in coordinate[0].split()] for coordinate in coordinates])
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.1 µs per loop
```

Make the data bigger:

```
long_coords = coordinates * 1000
```

But still, the pure Python version is the fastest:

```
%timeit np.array([np.fromstring(i, dtype=int, sep=' ') for j in long_coords for i in j])
100 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ms per loop

%timeit np.array([np.fromstring(item[0], dtype=int, sep=' ').tolist() for item in long_coords])
100 loops, best of 3: 14.2 ms per loop

%timeit np.array([[int(x)  for x in coordinate[0].split()] for coordinate in long_coords])
100 loops, best of 3: 7.54 ms per loop
```

Consistent results for even larger data:

```
very_long_coords = coordinates * 10000

%timeit np.array([np.fromstring(i, dtype=int, sep=' ') for j in very_long_coords for i in j])
10 loops, best of 3: 125 ms per loop

%timeit np.array([np.fromstring(item[0], dtype=int, sep=' ').tolist() for item in very_long_coords])
10 loops, best of 3: 140 ms per loop

%timeit np.array([[int(x)  for x in coordinate[0].split()] for coordinate in very_long_coords])
10 loops, best of 3: 73.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Just added `Approach #2` in my solution. Could you add that too in the benchmarks?

Comment: Gives me `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged` for NumPy '1.10.2'  on Python 3.5.

Comment: Did you get the error with `coordinates` or `long_coords` or `very_long_coords`?

Comment: With any. For example: `C = [['2 0'], ['0 1'], ['3 4']]`.

Comment: Hmm, works at my end on for NumPy '1.10.1' on Python 2.7. Hope it's not a version issue. Will add updated runtimes in my solution I guess, hope that's okay.

Comment: Works with Python 2. String/unicode issue? It's fine. Just go ahead.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`numpy.fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html):

```
coordinates_numpy = np.array([np.fromstring(i, dtype=int, sep=' ')
                             for j in coordinates for i in j])
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `C` as the input list, two approaches could be suggested to solve it.

**Approach #1 :** Using *one level* of list comprehension with [`np.fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) -

```
np.array([np.fromstring(item[0], dtype=int, sep=' ').tolist() for item in C])
```

**Approach #2 :** Vectorized approach using padding with [`np.core.defchararray.add`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.add.html) and then getting the separated numerals  -

```
np.fromstring(np.core.defchararray.add(C," "),dtype=int,sep=" ").reshape(len(C),-1)
```

Sample runs -

```
In [82]: C = [['2 0'], ['0 1'], ['3 4']]

In [83]: np.array([np.fromstring(item[0], dtype=int, sep=' ').tolist() for item in C])
Out[83]: 
array([[2, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [3, 4]])

In [84]: np.fromstring(np.core.defchararray.add(C, " "),dtype=int,sep=" ").reshape(len(C),-1)
Out[84]: 
array([[2, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
```

---

### Benchmarking

Borrowing the benchmarking code from [`@Mike Müller's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34650619/3293881), here are the runtimes for the `long_coords` and `very_long_coords` cases -

```
In [78]: coordinates = [["2 0"], ["0 1"], ["3 4"]]
    ...: long_coords = coordinates * 1000
    ...: %timeit np.array([np.fromstring(i, dtype=int, sep=' ') for j in long_coords for i in j])
    ...: %timeit np.array([np.fromstring(item[0], dtype=int, sep=' ').tolist() for item in long_coords])
    ...: %timeit np.array([[int(x)  for x in coordinate[0].split()] for coordinate in long_coords])
    ...: %timeit np.fromstring(np.core.defchararray.add(long_coords, " "), dtype=int,sep=" ").reshape(len(long_coords),-1)
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 7.27 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 9.52 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.84 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.73 ms per loop

In [79]: coordinates = [["2 0"], ["0 1"], ["3 4"]]
    ...: very_long_coords = coordinates * 10000
    ...: %timeit np.array([np.fromstring(i, dtype=int, sep=' ') for j in very_long_coords for i in j])
    ...: %timeit np.array([np.fromstring(item[0], dtype=int, sep=' ').tolist() for item in very_long_coords])
    ...: %timeit np.array([[int(x)  for x in coordinate[0].split()] for coordinate in very_long_coords])
    ...: %timeit np.fromstring(np.core.defchararray.add(very_long_coords, " "), dtype=int,sep=" ").reshape(len(very_long_coords),-1)
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 80.7 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 103 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 71 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 27.2 ms per loop
```