# Python: How to convert multiple list that have multiple digits into array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a text file with listed 4 x 3 binary values as such:

```
1 0 1
0 0 1
1 1 0
0 0 1
```

When I read this file in python, it is in this form:

```
import numpy as np
with open("test.txt")as g:
    p=g.read().splitlines()
    q=[];
    for m in p:
        q.append(int(m));
    p=q;
```

Python window:

```
>>> p
['1 0 1', '0 0 1', '1 1 0', '0 0 1']
```

How to convert it into array:

```
array([[ 1.0,  0.0,  1.0],
   [ 0.0,  0.0,  1.0],
   [ 1.0,  1.0,  0.0],
   [ 0.0,  0.0,  1.0]])
```

Comment: You should be seeing the [numpy load text](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) I think so.

Comment: Almost a clone of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650361/nesting-numpy-arrays-and-using-methods-like-splitting-them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over each `line` of `p`, split the string into separate numbers and, finally, convert each substring into a `float`:

```
import numpy as np

p = ['1 0 1', '0 0 1', '1 1 0', '0 0 1']
print np.array([map(float, line.split()) for line in p])
```

Output:

```
[[ 1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution by far is to skip all the intermediate steps of reading the file of your own and converting the lines to lists of lists and just use [numpy.loadtxt()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). The values will be of float type by default, so you won't have to do anything more.

```
import numpy as np

dat = np.loadtxt('test.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're guaranteed a sane enough input you can split the strings and convert the fragments to `int`:

```
def str2ints(l):
    return [int(frag) for frag in l.split()]
```

This function takes one line and splits it into parts, fx `"1 0 1"` are split into `["1", "0", "1"]` then I use list comprehension and converts the fragments to an int.

You use more of list comprehension to do it on the entire `p`:

```
[str2ints(l) for l in p]
```